# Javascript Constructor return value and function

Tags: javascript, constructor

How can i make countAge constructor like this with Javascript ?

```
const age = new countAge(21) // return 21
const agePlusOne = age.add(1) // return 22
```

Comment: Why would a constructor return a value and not an instance of the object? A normal function is better suited.

Comment: a constructor never returns a value, that's the purpose of the constructor

Comment: please check my answer, you can use `Species` in JavaScript

Comment: What do you mean by "*return 21*"?

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance with Number

```
class countAge extends Number {

  add(n) {
    return new countAge(this + n);
  }

}

var age = new countAge(21);
var agePlusOne  = age.add(1);
console.log(agePlusOne + 0);
```

An object can hold primitive value if the object itself inherited from such parent class

This is called `Species Pattern` -- Reference [Mozilla Developer Network: Species](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Species)

You can also use `Object.entend` similar to -- [Prototype.JS Number Object.entend uage](https://github.com/prototypejs/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/number.js)

Comment: No, this is not related to array species. Also, I would suggest to absolutely avoid extending `Number`

Comment: you can also use `Object.extend` similar to  -- https://github.com/prototypejs/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/number.js

Comment: …and you shouldn't do that either :-)

Comment: true, but there is more than one dedicated framework build with these principle for many years :) :)